# Error loading Tensorflow keras Model (.h5)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a number image and made a model file.

The corresponding sauce is as follows.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense 
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D

os.environ['TF_XLA_FLAGS'] = '--tf_xla_enable_xla_devices'

path = '/Users/animalman/Documents/test/cnn/'

trainPath = os.listdir(path+'train')
testPath = os.listdir(path+'test')

categories = ["5"]
length = len(categories)

width = 28
height = 28
label = [1 for i in range(length)]
X = []
Y = []
for idx, categorie in enumerate(categories):
    label = [0 for i in range(length)]
    label[idx] = 1
    
    fileDir = path + 'train' + '/' + categorie + '/'
    for t, dir, f in os.walk(fileDir):
        for filename in f:
            print(fileDir + filename)
            img = cv2.imread(fileDir + filename)
            img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=width/img.shape[0],fy=height/img.shape[1])
            X.append(img)
            Y.append(label)
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
X_train, X_test,Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y)
xy = (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test)


X_train = X_train.astype("float") / 256
X_test  = X_test.astype("float")  / 256

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=X_train.shape[1:], padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(512))  
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(length))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='rmsprop',
    metrics=['accuracy'])


hdf5_file = "./7obj-model.h5"
if os.path.exists(hdf5_file):
    model.load_weights(hdf5_file)
else:
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1)
    model.save_weights(hdf5_file)
```

And then I brought in the model file that was saved.

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(hdf5_file)
```

However, this is where the error occurs.
What's the reason?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/animalman/Documents/test/train.py", line 112, in 
> loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(hdf5_file)   File "/Users/animalman/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py",
> line 206, in load_model
> return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects,   File
> "/Users/animalman/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py",
> line 181, in load_model_from_hdf5
> raise ValueError('No model found in config file.') ValueError: No model found in config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/), your `h5` file only contains weights. You need to save your model architecture in a json file and then use `model_from_json`, to load model configuration, hence, you can load weights with `load_weights`.

Another option may be to simply save your model (architecture + weights together) by replacing your last line by

```py
model.save("model.h5")
```

and then to load, you can make use of

```py
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Oscar response, for smaller and simple models, `'h5'` format is sufficient but for complex models (Functional and subclassed) with custom_layers or custom metrics, it is better to save in `'tf'` format (also called as SavedModel format)

Check here for more detailed guide on [Keras webpage](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/)

> Keras SavedModel format limitations:
>
> The tracing done by SavedModel to produce the graphs of the layer call
> functions allows SavedModel be more portable than H5, but it comes
> with drawbacks.
>
> Can be slower and bulkier than H5. Cannot serialize the ops generated
> from the mask argument (i.e. if a layer is called with layer(...,
> mask=mask_value), the mask argument is not saved to SavedModel). Does
> not save the overridden train_step() in subclassed models. Custom
> objects that use masks or have a custom training loop can still be
> saved and loaded from SavedModel, except they must override
> get_config()/from_config(), and the classes must be passed to the
> custom_objects argument when loading.
>
> H5 limitations:
>
> External losses & metrics added via model.add_loss() &
> model.add_metric() are not saved (unlike SavedModel). If you have such
> losses & metrics on your model and you want to resume training, you
> need to add these losses back yourself after loading the model. Note
> that this does not apply to losses/metrics created inside layers via
> self.add_loss() & self.add_metric(). As long as the layer gets loaded,
> these losses & metrics are kept, since they are part of the call
> method of the layer. The computation graph of custom objects such as
> custom layers is not included in the saved file. At loading time,
> Keras will need access to the Python classes/functions of these
> objects in order to reconstruct the model. See Custom objects. Does
> not support preprocessing layers.

Answer (score 0):

model. save is geting me this error
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py:3103: UserWarning: You are saving your model as an HDF5 file via `model.save()`. This file format is considered legacy. We recommend using instead the native Keras format, e.g. `model.save('my_model.keras')`.
saving_api.save_model(